# Scala Phantom Cassandra insert method returns empty ResultSet

Tags: cassandra, insert, phantom-dsl

I want to insert data to my table in Cassandra and then return value from column "user_id" instead of full ResultSet. Here it is snippet of my code:

```
   def create(user: User): Future[UUID] = {
     insert
       .value(_.id, user.id)
       .value(_.email, user.email)
       .value(_.name, user.name)
       .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.ALL)
       .future()
       .map(r => fromRow(r.one()).id)
    }

   def fromRow(r: Row): User = {
     User(id(r), email(r), name(r))
   }
```

So future() returns Future[ResultSet]. After that I try to retrieve Row from ResultSet, modify it to User and get id eventually. Despite the fact that data were saved to my table I got

> ResultSet[ exhausted: true, Columns[]]

columns of the ResultSet are empty and consequently r.one() returned null.
I haven't found any examples for my purpose. So, can phantom-dsl do something like Quill?

```
val q = quote {
  query[Product].insert(lift(Product(0L, "My Product", 1011L))).returning(_.id)
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity what's the use case here?

Comment: I have REST API and post request that saves user to cassandra and I'd like to get response with id of saved user after insertion, for example {"code": "201 Created", "id": "ffffffff"}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in more recent versions of phantom that `create` method is automatically generated. More details [**here**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/docs/basics/tables.md#automatically-derived-store-method). The `fromRow` method is also automatically generated so you don't need to type it manually.

Long story short, this is what you could use:

```
def create(user: User): Future[UUID] = {
  store(user)
    .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.ALL)
    .future()
    .map(_ => user.id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You admitted my guess.